# How to make a footnote that shows it's referenced text where it's clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, html

I wanted to use something more elegant than brackets in my texts for long observations, extra information and etc, without breaking the flow. 
WordPress offers footnotes, I can do, for instance:

```
bla bla bla [^1] bla bla bla
... end of text
[^1]... that observation that I wanted to make
```

But that's hardly better than brackets, for when the reader clicks, he is taken to the bottom of the page, and while I'm writing, I have to go to the bottom of the page to write and then return to the main text. I would like to make the footnote show the reference floating over the text, when the user clicks or hover the mouse over, and if possible write both at the same line. Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need any JavaScript for this. Plain html will do:

```html
<div title="Your footnote here" class="has-footnote">
Your normal text here
</div>
```

Use the CSS class `.has-footnote` to make it obvious for the reader, that there is something to see.

Comment: Thank you, this is OK, but I wanted something else, that is, dynamic footnotes just like the ones in Wikipedia, where you just hover the cursor over footnotes, and a text balloon appears over it, showing the note. I guess for this I will need some javascript.